# What needs to run to stop the "start job... dev-disk-by\..." check on each boot?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, debian

I recently performed a VM disk resize, followed by a Gparted resize of `/dev/sda1`, followed by a *`dist-upgrade`* for Debian 8. I had to increase the VM disk size to accommodate the extra storage required for the upgrade.

Now, whenever I boot or reboot the VM, I get the following message along with its 1:30 second delay. The message is *`A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duui...{UUID}.device`*.

[image]

Searching for terms like *"Debian start job check disk"* tells me Debian (and Linux) does not use tools like check disk :o

What do I need to do or run to stop this start job once and for all?

Comment: If you Google the actual message, rather than paraphrasing it, you'll find things like [this](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/503587-Slow-boot-What-is-quot-A-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by-quot), which talks about checking your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Scott - Thanks. I did try Googling the actual message. What do you think happened because of the UUID? Anyway, it does not state what to run to stop it once an for all. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message indicates a problem in `/etc/fstab`. Run the `lsblk -f` command to view a list of your devices and their UUIDs. Then make sure the entries in `/etc/fstab` are using the correct UUIDs.

When I encountered this problem, my `/etc/fstab` had an entry for a swap partition, but `lsblk -f` revealed that I had no swap partition! Removing that entry from `/etc/fstab` solved the problem.

Helpful link: [A Start Job Is Running For dev-disk-by](https://donnutcompute.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by/)

Comment: Thanks. For completeness, UUIDs are not strictly needed. Disk names, like `/dev/sda1`, still work, and they survive operations like resizing (unlike UUIDs).

Comment: Older question, but I must add this comment for other folks who stumble upon this answer in google. /dev/sd[a-z][0-9] are not always going to be the same (unless you only have a single disk) and can change. Your best bet is to use labels on your filesystem and use them, as you set them yourself and as a general rule are much more memorable.